# iOS 5 SDK - custom reusable view/control

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am currently building some application for iOS. It is actually my second application.
However stick to the point. I need to design my own control/view. Let`s say rating view (stars). I have no idea how can I do that. It would be nice if it would support Interface Builder, but its not requirement. All I need is to do control/view that I can use in all my upcoming projects easily and configure them (in code is fine, settings like stars images, number of stars, etc..). If this is not entirely possible I am fine with that, but theres last requirement I really need, I need control/view I can easily use multiple times in one project in one view. The thing is I need one control to be multiple times in a row, generated automatically, something like cards that you scroll one to another from right to left and I dont need to keep those disappeared in left :)

I hope you understand what I want to achieve.

Thank you

**EDIT:**
Very well, I am asking you how to design my own control/view that I can use multiple times in project with different values.

Comment: Can you rephrase this into an actual question for us? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a star rating control you're after, check out http://cocoacontrols.com/. There are a few on there that you can download and drop into your project.

e.g. this one http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/mac-os-x/controls/edstarrating

In fact, download one of these and take a look as to how they're implemented. This should give you an idea of how to make your own.

Note: you can't directly use your own controls in Interface Builder on iPhone, which is a bit of a pain.

Comment: No, star rating control was just demo case, but thank you. I will definitely look at the code of it to see how its done. BTW: looking for iOS control, but I will help myself now on that site.